# Reset OSX Server password

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, webserver, administrator

I'm running Snow Leopard OSX Server. I haven't forgotten my password (everything I could find on the net involved resetting the password via command line if you've forgotten it). I can't find where to reset/update it.

As a side note, I noticed a strange thing where I can't change user passwords either, I change their passwords via the Workgroup Manager, click save, and nothing is updated.

Comment: Why can't you use the command line method even if you have not actually forgot the password?

Comment: I read something about this unsyncing your passwords. And it seems like there should be an easy GUI way to do this. If not, I'd like to know the easiest way to do this via command line. I've read a lot of contradictory information.